# How to get sub-sites of a sub-site?

Tags: groups, site, roles, membership

I'm working on a user control that should show all site names, within a given site, for the current FBA user. My site is structured using SP Groups, FBA Roles and FBA users, i.e.

> 'Harry' is a member of the 'CSAuthors_EN' role, and
>   'Melvin' is a member of the 'CSAuthors_FR' role and
>   both these roles are members of the 'CS - Authors' group.
>   The site that uses this group is: /customers/Authors

and

> 'Brandi' is a member of the 'CSAdmins_EN' role, and
>  
>   'Melvin' is a member of the 'CSAdmins_FR' role, and
>   both these roles are members of the 'CS - Admins' group.
>   The site that uses this group is: /customers/Admins

given that I know 'Melvin' is logged into the site (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser), I want to get a list that shows

```
Sites for 'Melvin'
>Authors
>Admins
```

To start I'm using SQL to query the FBA aspnet_UsersInRoles database for all the roles for the current user where the rolename starts with "CS" (i.e. CSAUthors, or CSAdmins). From this I know the RoleName. My thought is that I can then look at each sub-site within /customers/ for a site that has permissions for one of the roles, i.e. the /customers/Admins site has the group "CS - Admins", which has a member of the "CSAdmins_FR" role.

Sounds convoluted, I know - is there a better way? Can my idea even work? I'd appreciate any guidance at all

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is the answer to this my friend.

```
private StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();

private void CheckPermissionsOnWeb(SPWeb web, string groupName)
{
   foreach (SPGroup group in web.Groups)
   {
      if (group.Name == groupName)
         sc.Add(web.Url); // Or web.Name or whatever your custom logic is
   }

   foreach (SPWeb child in web.Webs)
   {
      CheckPermissionsOnWeb(child, groupName);
   }
}
```

You just need some explicit logic to map "CSAuthors_*" to "CS - Authors".

Comment: You just made me excited to get to work tomorrow so i can try this out! I'll let you know how it goes ;)

Comment: I would have used Stack(DFS)/Queue(BFS) for this purpose, using recursion may be quite a bit time consuming for large number of nested subsite and when the code will be executed at home page or any other page which user visits (this i assume) you should consider the running time

Comment: Can you elaborate on how DFS or BFS could be used in this case? I'm sure nested `foreach` or `do while` loops could be just as time consuming, but perhaps I'm looking at this wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the answer rj. Recursion was indeed the answer, with a little manipulation. Cheers!